# Android Realm ChangeListener not being triggered

Tags: android, realm

I've got a Realm results change listener that isn't being triggered, here's the code:

```
final RealmResults<LogEntry> entries = realm.where(LogEntry.class).findAll();

entries.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<LogEntry>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<LogEntry> results) {
                Log.v("Testing", "The size is: " + results.size());
            }
        });
```

There is definitely new stuff being added, I have a log on the realm insertion printing out the new size of the table, yet for some reason the change listener does nothing? Am I missing something here, it seems identical to the docs.

Comment: How do we use realm Transaction inside onChange method?

Comment: This article explains everything about realm and its MUCH better than their official documentation
https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to keep a class reference to `entries` to prevent it from being GC'ed:

```
public MyClass {

  private RealmResults<LogEntry> entries;

  public void myMethod() {

    entries = realm.where(LogEntry.class).findAll();
    entries.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<LogEntry>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<LogEntry> results) {
                Log.v("Testing", "The size is: " + results.size());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, but it worked after I removed listener         ```entries.removeAllChangeListeners()```

Comment: Can you please look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960419/what-are-the-chances-that-the-order-of-changelistener-being-called-in-different

Comment: Is it safe to call ```findAll()``` function from the UI thread? My collection is quite large.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `realmChangeListener`, then make your `RealmResult<E>` variable a Global variable. Only then it will get triggered on database change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `findAll()`, I used `findAllAsync()` and saved its result globally. Then added listener to that global variable. This is only approach that worked in my case.

UPD: Also, try to use this listener from a different thread. Apparently, that's also can be an issue.